# Getting a list of all event listeners, javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a list of links that GET appropriate file upon clicking on appropriate link with ajax.

Let's say I've got a few files in "pages" folder called a.php and b.php. Upon pressing on first link I get all the data from file a.php, same goes for b.php.

The problem is that if first I open a.php and fill div with this line of code:

```
$("#content").html(data);
```

Then I open file b.php and overwrite previously created data with new one that I got from my 2nd file, then the event listeners from file a.php doesn't get overwritten.

So how could I solve this problem? Thank You.

------------------EDIT----------------------

Here's the function I'm using to get data

```
function openPage()
{
    var targetPage = $(this).data("page-file-name");
    $("#loader").css("display", "block");

    $.ajax(
    {
        method: "GET",
        url: "pages/"+targetPage
    }).done(function(data) 
    { 
        $("#container *").remove();
        $("#container").html(data);
        $("#loader").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `jQuery.remove` method to remove all the existing DOM nodes as well as the data and event. After that use the `html` method to insert new DOM nodes.

See [jQuery Remove documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: I've tried  using the remove method this way 
$("#loader").css("display", "block");
    
$.ajax(
{
 method: "GET",
 url: "pages/"+targetPage
}).done(function(data) 
{ 
 $("#container *").remove();
 $("#container").html(data);
 $("#loader").css("display", "none");
 });

But the events doesn't get removed.

Comment: Can you add more detailed code snippets to your original post.